# Когда нажимаешь "отправить" и ничего не ввёл,то ничего не происходит,а должно выводиться Введите имя ,или Введите текст комментария.Буду благодарен

Tags: php

```
<div id="yakor" class="container4">
<form class="form" method="POST" action="test.ru/includes/articles.php?id=<?php echo $art['id'];?>">
<?php
  if( isset($_POST['do_post']) )
  {
    $errors = array();

    if($_POST['name'] == '' )
    {
      $errors[] = 'Введите имя!';
    }

    if($_POST['text'] == '' )
    {
      $errors[] = 'Введите текст комментария!';
    }

    if( empty($errors)  )
    {
      // ДОБАВИТЬ КОМЕНТАРИЙ
    } else
    {
      // вывод ошибки комментария 
      echo $errors['0'] . '<hr>';
    }
  }
?>
<div>
<form method="POST" class="name_input_koment">
<input id="komentname" placeholder="Введите имя" type="text" name="name">
</form>
<form method="POST" class="text_input_koment">
<input id="koment" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Напишите свой комментарий">
</form>
<form method="POST" class="otp_input_koment">
<input id="otp" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['do_post']` - так такого имени и не существует

Comment: Всмысле?Я просто начинающий.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'send')) {
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $text = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'text');
    if (!$name or !$text) {
        echo "Вы не ввели или ввели не все данные";
    } else {
        // тут что-то делаем с переменными $name и $text
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Тестовая форма</legend>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Введите имя">
        <input name="text" placeholder="Напишите свой комментарий">
        <button name="send">Отправить</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```